# Regularity of elliptic equation with Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde, regularity

In the context of the regularity of the free boundary of the one-phase (a.k.a. Bernoulli) problem we want to show $C^{1,\alpha}$ regularity of the free boundary implies smoothness of the free boundary at regular points.

Assume $\Omega$ to be a bounded domain.

**Question 1:** Let $w\in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$ satisfy
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} \operatorname{div}(A \, \nabla w) = 0 & \text{in } \Omega,\\ \partial_\nu w=0 & \text{on } \partial\Omega, \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $A\succ0$ sufficiently regular (e.g. $\in C^{k,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)$) and $\partial \Omega \in C^{k+1,\alpha}$. Then $w\in C^{k,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)$?

**Question 2:** Let $w\in C^{\alpha}(\bar \Omega)\cap W^{1,2}(\bar\Omega)$ satisfy
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases} \operatorname{div}(A \, \nabla w) = 0 & \text{in } \Omega,\\ \partial_\nu w=0 & \text{on } \partial\Omega, \end{cases}
\end{equation}
weakly. That is for $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\bar \Omega)$,
\begin{equation} 
\int_\Omega A \, \nabla w \cdot \nabla \varphi =  0=\int_{ \partial \Omega_u} A \, \nabla w \cdot \nu  \varphi \qquad \forall \varphi \in C_c^\infty ( \bar \Omega_u).
\end{equation}
Assume that $A\succ0$ is sufficiently regular (e.g. $\in C^\alpha(\bar \Omega)$) and $\partial \Omega \in C^{1,\alpha}$. Then $w\in C^{1,\alpha}(\bar \Omega)$?

Comment: I gather the actual questions are to show the final assertions given the rest of the 'question'? Where do these questions come from?

Comment: When you say $A>0$ you mean $A$ is a scalar, or do you mean in the sense of quadratic forms?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are asking, as the thing you have under-bracketed is just false. If you are looking for Schauder theorems for oblique derivative problems, I suggest Gary Lieberman's book on the topic. If you are confused between the normal and conormal derivative, I'm not sure what to recommend (Evans PDE?). If you want to show higher regularity of free boundaries, consult Kinderlehrer Nirenberg Spruck.